# JQuery mobile multiline button override issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using Phonegap and JQuery mobile to create an app that uses button whose content (caption) is fetched via an ajax request and can be pretty long, so I wanted to have multiline buttons. I searched and found a way to do so by using the following css :

```
.ui-btn-inner{
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

But I can't get it to work.

I have tried to put it between style tags in the head of my page, then inside the html code of the button itself using style='' . I also tried to put that piece of code in a css file and link it to the page but it doesn't work either, even if I put this file in the same folder than my HTML.

Here is an extract of my JS where I create the button :

```
for ( var i = 0; i < quizz.questionnaire[index_quest - 1].propositions.length; i++) {
    if (quizz.questionnaire[index_quest - 1].fin) {
        if (i + 1 == quizz.questionnaire[index_quest - 1].reponse) {
            code_source += "<a href='pageFinQz.html' data-role='button' onclick='localStorage.localScore=++score'>";
            code_source += quizz.questionnaire[index_quest - 1].propositions[i];
            code_source += "</a><br/>";
        } else {
            code_source += "<a href='pageFinQz.html' data-role='button'>";
            code_source += quizz.questionnaire[index_quest - 1].propositions[i];
            code_source += "</a><br/>";
        }
    } else if (i + 1 == quizz.questionnaire[index_quest - 1].reponse) {
        code_source += "<a href='#' data-role='button' onclick='mapQuestion(quizz, ++index_quest); localStorage.localScore=++score; return false' rel='external'>";
        code_source += quizz.questionnaire[index_quest - 1].propositions[i];
        code_source += "</a><br/>";
    } else {
        code_source += "<a href='#' data-role='button' onclick='mapQuestion(quizz, ++index_quest); return false' rel='external'>";
        code_source += quizz.questionnaire[index_quest - 1].propositions[i];
        code_source += "</a><br/>";
    }
}
```

And the head of my HTML is :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text-html" charset="UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jqm/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
```

style.css is in the same folder than my HTML and contains exactly :

```
.ui-btn-inner{
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

I don't really understand why the css seems to not work since it's pretty simple, but maybe I missed something obvious.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: buttons render normally and get styled with jQM? if so, it should work with no issues. anyway try to override `.ui-btn-text` instead.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, and thank you and Simon for your answers. After the proposition of Simon I tried solutions related to his suggestions. I also tried to do as you said Omar, but none of it worked, though the buttons are indeed correctly styled (but truncated if too long of course).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what is going on without a jsfiddle or example but why not try use:

```
display: block;
```

directly on the link element `<a href="" style="display: block;"></a>`

From the looks of things `.ui-btn-inner` is referring to the inside of the button and the hyperlink in your code does not seem to have a class assigned to it.